# Swift constraints unable to move back to bottom of screen after adjusting constraint height

Tags: ios, swift, swift5

I have a button which is using auto layout to sit at the bottom of the screen. I am trying to make the button adjust position to always be above the keyboard. So far, I have been able to get the button to move up but I am unable to get the position of the button to reset.

I am doing everything completely programmatically and Im not using Storyboards at all. A solution without outlets would be much appreciated.

My `viewDidLoad` function (Only showing the logic related to the button movement)

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardMovedUp(notification:)), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)

NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardMovedDown(notification:)), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
```

The `keyboardMovedUp` function

```
@objc
func keyboardMovedUp(notification: Notification) {
    if let userInfo = notification.userInfo {
        let endFrame = (userInfo[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue
        let viewEndFrame = view.convert(endFrame!, from: view.window)
        let endFrameY = endFrame?.origin.y ?? 0
        let animationRate = (userInfo[UIResponder.keyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as? NSNumber)?.doubleValue
        let animationCurveRawNSM = userInfo[UIResponder.keyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] as? NSNumber
        let animationCurveRaw = animationCurveRawNSM?.uintValue ?? UIView.AnimationOptions.curveEaseInOut.rawValue
        let animationCurve: UIView.AnimationOptions = UIView.AnimationOptions(rawValue: animationCurveRaw)

        self.moveUp = self.continueButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor, constant: -viewEndFrame.origin.y)
        self.moveUp?.isActive = true

        UIView.animate(withDuration: animationRate!, delay: TimeInterval(0), options: animationCurve, animations: {
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

and my `keyboardMovedDown` function

```
@objc
func keyboardMovedDown(notification: Notification) {
    if let userInfo = notification.userInfo {
        let endFrame = (userInfo[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue

        self.moveUp?.isActive = false
        self.moveDown = self.continueButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor, constant: -20)
        self.moveDown?.isActive = true


        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25) {
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }
}
```

With this code the button will move up when the keyboard is displayed but the button does not move places once the keyboard is reset.

I was able to get the code to work by modifying the `origin.y` parameter of the button but I have heard this can cause compatibility issues with autolayout.

**Edit: @IchBinStudenten This what my current code looks like with your changes**

```
func viewDidLoad() {
     self.moveUp = self.continueButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor, constant: -20)
     self.moveUp?.isActive = true

}

@objc
func keyboardMoved(notification: Notification) {
    if let userInfo = notification.userInfo {
        let endFrame = (userInfo[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue
        let viewEndFrame = view.convert(endFrame!, from: view.window)
        let endFrameY = endFrame?.origin.y ?? 0
        let animationRate = (userInfo[UIResponder.keyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as? NSNumber)?.doubleValue
        let animationCurveRawNSM = userInfo[UIResponder.keyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] as? NSNumber
        let animationCurveRaw = animationCurveRawNSM?.uintValue ?? UIView.AnimationOptions.curveEaseInOut.rawValue
        let animationCurve: UIView.AnimationOptions = UIView.AnimationOptions(rawValue: animationCurveRaw)

        self.moveUp?.constant = -viewEndFrame.height - 20

        UIView.animate(withDuration: animationRate!, delay: TimeInterval(0), options: animationCurve, animations: {
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }, completion: nil)
    }
}

@objc
func keyboardMovedDown(notification: Notification) {
    if let userInfo = notification.userInfo {

        self.moveUp?.constant = 0

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25) {
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using 1 constraint is enough to achieve what you want. You are using one constraint anyway. Set `self.moveUp` active when keyboard moves up, and change its value

```
self.moveUp?.constant = -20.0
```

when keyboard moves down. To keep the code cleaner, just keep a reference to `self.continueButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo:self.view.bottomAnchor)` by creating some variable inside of your class, so that you can modify its *constant* property only. E.g.:

```
let keyboardConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint

override func viewDidLoad() {
   self.keyboardConstraint = self.continueButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor)
   self.keyboardConstraint.isActive = true
}

@objc
func keyboardMovedUp(notification: Notification) {
        /// ...your code 
        self.keyboardConstraint.constant = -viewEndFrame.origin.y

        UIView.animate(withDuration: animationRate!, delay: TimeInterval(0), options: animationCurve, animations: {
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }, completion: nil)
    }
}

@objc
func keyboardMovedDown(notification: Notification) {
    if let userInfo = notification.userInfo {
        let endFrame = (userInfo[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue

        self.keyboardConstraint.constant = -20.0

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25) {
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }
}
```

Another option is to install [IQKeyboardManager](https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager) via CocoaPods which manages it all for you.

Let me know if that solves your problem.

Comment: I have tried these changes but I still get the same result. The button will move up when the keyboard is opening but the button does not move once it resets...

Comment: I have updated my post with the changes if you would like to take a look

Comment: Then you can try to use 2 constraints with different values and try to modify their priorities by setting `UILayoutPriorityDefaultHigh` and/or `UILayoutPriorityDefaultLow` to respective constraints. @bsoleimany

Answer (score 2):

For convenience, make the constraint an instance property:

```
private lazy var continueButtonBottomAnchor = continueButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: -bottomSafeArea)
```

Activate it in `loadView` when you add it as a subview:

```
continueButtonBottomAnchor.isActive = true
```

`bottomSafeArea` is a computed property because I assume you want to position the button on the bottom safe area. Computed properties don't store values (compute only) so you can access them lazily in these notifications with the correct values.

```
@objc private func keyboardMovedUp(_ notification: Notification) {
    guard let keyboardFrame = notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue else {
        return
    }
    continueButtonBottomAnchor.constant = -keyboardFrame.cgRectValue.height   
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0, animations: {
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    })
}

@objc private func keyboardMovedDown() {
    continueBUttonBottomAnchor.constant = -bottomSafeArea // using our computed property
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0, animations: {
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    })
}
```

Unlike the accepted answer, do not add your own, or attempt to get, animation parameters (duration and timing); by animating inside the notification, those parameters will be applied automatically so your constraint will move with the keyboard in perfect sync.

Comment: I have tried this with no success. Once the button is moved up, it is never able to go back down. I am only able to move it farther up, any code to make the button move down does nothing.

Comment: This code by itself will work 100% of the time. Something else is getting in your way.

Comment: I appear to have fixed the issue by moving my set constraints out of the `viewDidLayoutSubviews` function and putting them into `viewDidLoad` function. If you happen to know why this happened would you be able to explain it?

Comment: Also would you be able to tell me which functions are the correct functions for setting up constraints? Should it all be defaulted into the `viewDidLoad` function? I was trying to make my code a bit cleaner but I guess I broke it even more :P

Comment: If you’re doing everything programmatically, you should be doing all of your foundational UI construction in loadView, like adding subviews and their constraints. Use viewDidLoad for things that need to be done afterwards like applying notifications or getting data from the network.

Comment: Ah I see, thank you for the response. I will modify my codebase to match this answer.

Comment: loadView is where storyboard does all of its work and since you’re not using it it’s where you need to do all of your UI work. That’s why storyboard programmers never use it, all of their work is viewDidLoad or later.